# Stream data via mtp

Tags: mtp, usb-mass-storage

Android has removed support for UMS (USB Mass Storage) in favor of MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) for connecting to a computer.

MTP works similar in terms of copying and pasting files and folders to and from the Nexus device, but for example if there's a movie file, double clicking it on Windows requires it to be copied locally first instead of just starting my media player like a normal UMS storage would.

Any way to stream movies like this using MTP?

Comment: For more details on this issue, look [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1714827). Perhaps you can mount it as a network drive?

Comment: You can run an FTP/Web server on Android, and can stream movies on PC. See my [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277) or other answers there. This way your system won't download the whole file temporarily, which is a mess. I use the solution a lot.

Answer (score 0):

VLC linux has a plugin for MTP streaming(libmtp_plugin). Sadly Windows version is lacking one - https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=121275.